# How can I compare a string against a carriage return 0x0D?

Tags: c++, string, compare, newline

I'm having some trouble passing the return carriage value to a std::string function.

```
std::string parsedWord;
size_t found = str.find_first_not_of(' ');
if (found == std::string::npos) std::cout << "No non-whitespace characters found\n";
    else
        {
            while (str.compare(found, 1, " ") || str.compare(found, 1, 0x0D )
    // The last argument should be a const char*. 
            {
                    parsedWord += str[found]; found++;
            }
        }
```

I specifically want to compare against the value 0x0D, because on Windows systems new line is CR LF and other systems use different types, I just want to check against 0x0D

Comment: How about parsing it to char, like `char(0x0D)`?

Comment: you have '\r' and '\n' chars for end-line carriage-return chars... But why not simply use isspace function that will handle all white spaces

Comment: What is the purpose of the loop you have? To remove whitespace? Then I suggest you check what the `compare` function [*returns*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare#Return_value).

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
while (str.compare(found, 1, " ") || str.compare(found, 1, "\r")
```

Comment: But how do I know what "\r" is? between systems it's either CR LF, LF CR, just CR, it's really confusing. I tried something like const char* = &((const char)0x0D) but no luck

Comment: Maybe give an explanation of how this works? Ie. what's '\r'?

Comment: @Zebrafish '\r' is the carriage return character. It's always the same. '\n' is the new line character. Some systems use both in combination (ie. Windows), some only use the new line character (ie. Linux).

Comment: So there's a difference between "\n" and "\r"?

Comment: @Zebrafish Of course. They're 2 separate characters.

Comment: Oh great, I guess that'll work. Thanks. Just wondering if there's a way to cast, seems like something I should be able to do, as chars are just numbers, they should have values too.

Comment: @Zebrafish "\r" is a C-string (const char*), but '\r' is a character (const char). Do also read [how to handle line endings in Unicode](http://utf8everywhere.org/#faq.crlf) (that said, the whole document is very much worth reading!).